# Cheap Android tablet with USB OTG webcam support

Tags: usb, android, tablet

I am looking for an Android tablet which has USB [OTG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_On-The-Go) webcam support.

The tablet should have the following features:

- Between 6 and 14 inches in screen size
- Fanless
- Cost less than $200 (negotiable)
- Be fast enough to display 720p webcam input

What are some decent Android tablets that fit this set of features?

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/36887/how-can-i-determine-if-my-device-has-usb-host-mode-otg-support